# Angular how to delay provider running until a dependent service resolves its promises

Tags: angular, provider

I am trying to add run time configs into my app but getting an issue when creating an APOLLO_OPTIONS via a ngModule prodiver.

my config values in the factory for APOLLO_OPTIONS come back as null as the APP_INITIALIZER fires first to run its factory but before it resolves its promise with the data the APOLLO_OPTIONS runs.

Config service

```
@Injectable()
export class AppConfigService {
  private appConfig = {} as IAppConfig;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  async  loadAppConfig() {
    var config = '/assets/data/appConfig.json';

    return this.http.get(config)
      .toPromise()
      .then(data => {
        const thig = <IAppConfig>data 

        this.appConfig = thig;
      });
  }

  getConfig() {
    return this.appConfig;
  }
}
```

App moduel

```
// const appInitializerFn = (appConfig: AppConfigService) => {
//     return () => {
//         appConfig.loadAppConfig();
//     };
// };

export function appInitializerFn(appConfig: AppConfigService): () => Promise<any> {
    return () => appConfig.loadAppConfig();
}

...

@NgModule({
...
    imports: [
         GraphQLModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        AppConfigService,
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: appInitializerFn,
            multi: true,
            deps: [AppConfigService]
        },
    ],
...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

graphql.moduel

```
export function createApollo(httpLink: HttpLink, appConfigService: AppConfigService): 
ApolloClientOptions<any> {
...

  var thing = appConfigService.getConfig().hasuraUrl;

  return {
...
  };
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
      useFactory: createApollo,
      deps: [HttpLink, AppConfigService],
    },
  ],
})
export class GraphQLModule {

  ngOnInit() {
...
}
```

For the life of me i cant delay or wait for the loadAppConfig func to return data into the createApollo func, i have even tried calling directly and awaiting it but i am unable to await in a provider factory

This works for all my other services where i can inject my AppConfigService into constructors